# Копирование стиля картинки по клику на нее

Tags: javascript, html, css

Народ всем привет, помогите реализовать. Есть картинка на которую можно наложить разные фильтры: контраст, яркость и тд. - как сделать так что бы при клике на нее копировался стиль примененных к ней фильтров.

```js
//on click of go(submit) button, addImage() will be called
$("#go").click(addImage);

//on pressing return, addImage() will be called
$("#urlBox").submit(addImage);


// editing image via css properties
function editImage() {
    var gs = $("#gs").val(); // grayscale
    var blur = $("#blur").val(); // blur
    var br = $("#br").val(); // brightness
    var ct = $("#ct").val(); // contrast
    var huer = $("#huer").val(); //hue-rotate
    var opacity = $("#opacity").val(); //opacity
    var invert = $("#invert").val(); //invert
    var saturate = $("#saturate").val(); //saturate
    var sepia = $("#sepia").val(); //sepia

    $("#imageContainer img").css(
    "filter", 'grayscale(' + gs+
    '%) blur(' + blur +
    'px) brightness(' + br +
    '%) contrast(' + ct +
    '%) hue-rotate(' + huer +
    'deg) opacity(' + opacity +
    '%) invert(' + invert +
    '%) saturate(' + saturate +
    '%) sepia(' + sepia + '%)'
  );

    $("#imageContainer img").css(
    "-webkit-filter", 'grayscale(' + gs+
    '%) blur(' + blur +
    'px) brightness(' + br +
    '%) contrast(' + ct +
    '%) hue-rotate(' + huer +
    'deg) opacity(' + opacity +
    '%) invert(' + invert +
    '%) saturate(' + saturate +
    '%) sepia(' + sepia + '%)'
  );
}

//When sliders change image will be updated via editImage() function
$("input[type=range]").change(editImage).mousemove(editImage);

// Reset sliders back to their original values on press of 'reset'
$('#imageEditor').on('reset', function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
        editImage();
    }, 0);
});

// adding an image via url box
function addImage(e) {
    var imgUrl = $("#imgUrl").val();
    if (imgUrl.length) {
        $("#imageContainer img").attr("src", imgUrl);
    }
    e.preventDefault(); 
}
```

```css
/* General styles for the page */ 
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #D2D7D3;
  font-family: monospace;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 960px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 25px 0 25px 0;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

hr {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

form {
  text-align: center;
}

/* Styles for  URL box */ 

.url-box {
  background-color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #b3b3b1;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
  margin: 0px 0px;
  width: 50%;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #000;
}

#go {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 4px solid #b3b3b1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #000;
}

/* Styles for image container*/

#imageContainer {
  border: 2px solid grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 65%;
  max-width: 600px;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
}

#imageContainer img {
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Styles for sliders*/

.sliders {
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.sliders p {
  margin: 18px 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.sliders label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #22313F;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.sliders input {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 20px 0 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

input[type=range] {
  /*removes default webkit styles*/
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  /*fix for FF unable to apply focus style bug */
  border-radius: 5px;
  /*required for proper track sizing in FF*/
  width: 150px;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 300px;
  height: 7px;
  background: #ABB7B7;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4B77BE;
  margin-top: -6px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type=range]:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}


#reset {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 4px solid #b3b3b1;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.p {
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  padding:  40px 0 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Image Editor with CSS Filters and jQuery</h1>
        
<!--Form for collecting image URL -->
<form id="urlBox" class="center">
  <input class="url-box" type="url" id="imgUrl" placeholder="Paste any image link and start playing!">
  <input id="go" type="button" value="Go">
</form>

<hr color="grey">

<!--Controls for CSS filters via range input-->
<div class="sliders">
  <form id="imageEditor">
    <p>
      <label for="gs">Grayscale</label>
      <input id="gs" name="gs" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0">
    </p>

    <p>
      <label for="blur">Blur</label>
      <input id="blur" name="blur" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0">
    </p>

    <p>
      <label for="br">Exposure</label>
      <input id="br" name="br" type="range" min="0" max="200" value="100">
    </p>

    <p>
      <label for="ct">Contrast</label>
      <input id="ct" name="ct" type="range" min="0" max="200" value="100">
    </p>

    <p>
      <label for="huer">Hue Rotate</label>
      <input id="huer" name="huer" type="range" min="0" max="360" value="0">
    </p>

    <p>
      <label for="opacity">Opacity</label>
      <input id="opacity" name="opacity" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100">
    </p>

    <p>
      <label for="invert">Invert</label>
      <input id="invert" name="invert" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0">
    </p>

    <p>
      <label for="saturate">Saturate</label>
      <input id="saturate" name="saturate" type="range" min="0" max="500" value="100">
    </p>

    <p>
      <label for="sepia">Sepia</label>
      <input id="sepia" name="sepia" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0">
    </p>

    <input type="reset" form="imageEditor" id="reset" value="Reset" />

  </form>
</div>  

<!--container where image will be loaded-->
<div id="imageContainer" class="center">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/123941/stadium.jpg">
</div>

<p class="p">Demo by Vikas Lalwani. <a href="http://www.sitepoint.com/build-simple-image-editor-with-css-filters-jquery" target="_blank">See article</a>.</p>
```

Comment: Вам нужно чтоб копировалось значение параметров Grayscale, Blur и тд?

Comment: @2ip да - можно даже кнопкой или тактовым полем вывести, я сама не представляю как это сделать. Картинке присваиваются стили: filter: grayscale(0%) blur(0px) brightness(100%) contrast(100%) hue-rotate(
0deg
) opacity(100%) invert(0%) saturate(100%) sepia(0%); и вот их хотелось бы как то вывести.